# Python pandas Filtering out nan from a data selection of a column of strings

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Without using `groupby` how would I filter out data without `NaN`?

Let say I have a matrix where customers will fill in `'N/A','n/a'` or any of its variations and others leave it blank:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df = pd.DataFrame({'movie': ['thg', 'thg', 'mol', 'mol', 'lob', 'lob'],
                  'rating': [3., 4., 5., np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
                  'name': ['John', np.nan, 'N/A', 'Graham', np.nan, np.nan]})

nbs = df['name'].str.extract('^(N/A|NA|na|n/a)')
nms=df[(df['name'] != nbs) ]
```

output:

```
>>> nms
  movie    name  rating
0   thg    John       3
1   thg     NaN       4
3   mol  Graham     NaN
4   lob     NaN     NaN
5   lob     NaN     NaN
```

How would I filter out `NaN` values so I can get results to work with like this:

```
  movie    name  rating
0   thg    John       3
3   mol  Graham     NaN
```

I am guessing I need something like `~np.isnan` but the tilda does not work with strings.

Comment: df[df.name.notnull()]

Answer (score 338, accepted):

Just drop them:

```
nms.dropna(thresh=2)
```

this will drop all rows where there are at least two non-`NaN`.

Then you could then drop where name is `NaN`:

```
In [87]:

nms
Out[87]:
  movie    name  rating
0   thg    John       3
1   thg     NaN       4
3   mol  Graham     NaN
4   lob     NaN     NaN
5   lob     NaN     NaN

[5 rows x 3 columns]
In [89]:

nms = nms.dropna(thresh=2)
In [90]:

nms[nms.name.notnull()]
Out[90]:
  movie    name  rating
0   thg    John       3
3   mol  Graham     NaN

[2 rows x 3 columns]
```

**EDIT**

Actually looking at what you originally want you can do just this without the `dropna` call:

```
nms[nms.name.notnull()]
```

**UPDATE**

Looking at this question 3 years later, there is a mistake, firstly [`thresh`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) arg looks for at least `n` non-`NaN` values so in fact the output should be:

```
In [4]:
nms.dropna(thresh=2)

Out[4]:
  movie    name  rating
0   thg    John     3.0
1   thg     NaN     4.0
3   mol  Graham     NaN
```

It's possible that I was either mistaken 3 years ago or that the version of pandas I was running had a bug, both scenarios are entirely possible.

Answer (score 405):

**Simplest of all solutions:**

```
filtered_df = df[df['name'].notnull()]
```

Thus, it filters out only rows that doesn't have NaN values in 'name' column.

*For multiple columns:*

```
filtered_df = df[df[['name', 'country', 'region']].notnull().all(1)]
```

Answer (score 17):

```
df.dropna(subset=['columnName1', 'columnName2'])
```

Answer (score 10):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'movie': ['thg', 'thg', 'mol', 'mol', 'lob', 'lob'],'rating': [3., 4., 5., np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],'name': ['John','James', np.nan, np.nan, np.nan,np.nan]})

for col in df.columns:
    df = df[~pd.isnull(df[col])]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [`query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

```
out = df.query("name.notna() & name !='N/A'", engine='python')
```

Output:

```
  movie  rating    name
0   thg     3.0    John
3   mol     NaN  Graham
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information like citations or documentation about the use of query.

Answer (score 1):

Inside [`query()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) pass `column_name == column_name` to keep the rows where `column_name` is not `NA`.

For your case:

```
nms.query('name == name')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can filter negative to columns with na values:
dt = dt[~dt[columns_to_filter].isna().all(1)]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).