# querying panda df to filter rows where a column is not Nan

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, nan, pandasql

I am new to python and using pandas.

I want to query a dataframe and filter the rows where one of the columns is not `NaN`.

I have tried:

```
a=dictionarydf.label.isnull()
```

but a is populated with `true` or `false`.
Tried this

```
dictionarydf.query(dictionarydf.label.isnull())
```

but gave an error as I expected

sample data:

```
      reference_word         all_matching_words  label review
0           account             fees - account    NaN      N
1           account           mobile - account    NaN      N
2           account          monthly - account    NaN      N
3    administration  delivery - administration    NaN      N
4    administration      fund - administration    NaN      N
5           advisor             fees - advisor    NaN      N
6           advisor          optimum - advisor    NaN      N
7           advisor              sub - advisor    NaN      N
8             aichi           delivery - aichi    NaN      N
9             aichi               pref - aichi    NaN      N
10          airport              biz - airport    travel      N
11          airport              cfo - airport    travel      N
12          airport           cfomtg - airport    travel      N
13          airport          meeting - airport    travel      N
14          airport           summit - airport    travel      N
15          airport             taxi - airport    travel      N
16          airport            train - airport    travel      N
17          airport         transfer - airport    travel      N
18          airport             trip - airport    travel      N
19              ais                admin - ais    NaN      N
20              ais               alpine - ais    NaN      N
21              ais                 fund - ais    NaN      N
22       allegiance       custody - allegiance    NaN      N
23       allegiance          fees - allegiance    NaN      N
24            alpha               late - alpha    NaN      N
25            alpha               meal - alpha    NaN      N
26            alpha               taxi - alpha    NaN      N
27           alpine             admin - alpine    NaN      N
28           alpine               ais - alpine    NaN      N
29           alpine              fund - alpine    NaN      N
```

I want to filter the data where label is not NaN

expected output:

```
     reference_word         all_matching_words   label    review
0          airport              biz - airport    travel      N
1          airport              cfo - airport    travel      N
2          airport           cfomtg - airport    travel      N
3          airport          meeting - airport    travel      N
4          airport           summit - airport    travel      N
5          airport             taxi - airport    travel      N
6          airport            train - airport    travel      N
7          airport         transfer - airport    travel      N
8          airport             trip - airport    travel      N
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python pandas Filtering out nan from a data selection of a column of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22551403/python-pandas-filtering-out-nan-from-a-data-selection-of-a-column-of-strings)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html):

```
df = df.dropna(subset=['label'])

print (df)
   reference_word  all_matching_words   label review
10        airport       biz - airport  travel      N
11        airport       cfo - airport  travel      N
12        airport    cfomtg - airport  travel      N
13        airport   meeting - airport  travel      N
14        airport    summit - airport  travel      N
15        airport      taxi - airport  travel      N
16        airport     train - airport  travel      N
17        airport  transfer - airport  travel      N
18        airport      trip - airport  travel      N
```

Another solution - [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`notnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.notnull.html):

```
df = df[df.label.notnull()]

print (df)
   reference_word  all_matching_words   label review
10        airport       biz - airport  travel      N
11        airport       cfo - airport  travel      N
12        airport    cfomtg - airport  travel      N
13        airport   meeting - airport  travel      N
14        airport    summit - airport  travel      N
15        airport      taxi - airport  travel      N
16        airport     train - airport  travel      N
17        airport  transfer - airport  travel      N
18        airport      trip - airport  travel      N
```

Comment: thanks for the quick answer :) @jezrael that solved the problem. I opted for the boolean indexing because i don't want to drop the rows and i need not create a duplicate dataframe as well. Both the solutions worked perfect