# pandas change value to nan

Tags: pandas, dataframe, nan

I'm using a pandas dataframe which looks something like this:

[image]

and I need to change all the values of `-999` to `Nan` for processing. The [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html), and the following articles,

[here](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2016/01/12-pandas-techniques-python-data-manipulation/)

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22551403/python-pandas-filtering-out-nan-from-a-data-selection-of-a-column-of-strings)

describe how to change `NaN`s to values, but I need to go the other way. What method can I use to achieve this?

I've also tried `sources.replace(-999, np.nan)` but this didn't seem to have an effect. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to assign the result back or use sources.replace(-999, np.nan, inplace = True)

Comment: Whoops, thank you for pointing that out. A simple mistake.