# How to convert integer type array (with some NaN) to string type array

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have an array `x` and one of the values is `NaN`.

`x = [1, 2, NaN, 3, 5]`

All the elements are integer excepting `NaN`.
This array type is regarded as float64 not int.

I would like to convert type from floating to string.

I tried `astype(str)`. But this make decimal point such as `x = [1.0, 2.0, NaN, 3.0, 5.0]`

I tried `astype(int).astype(str)`. However, in this case, it doesn't work due to NaN element.

So, how I can convert integer array with some of element are NaN to string type without decimal point?

Thank you for reading.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'x' : [1,2, np.nan ,3,5]})

# df.dtypes

df['x'] = df['x'].astype(str)
# In this case, it make decimal point.

df['x'] = df['x'].astype(int).astype(str)
# It doesn't work due to NaN element.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
df1 = df.replace(np.nan, '', regex=True)
```

This might help. It will replace all NaNs with an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter out Nans rather than replacing with ''

```
filtered_df = df[df['x'].notnull()]
```

Source: [Python pandas Filtering out nan from a data selection of a column of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22551403/python-pandas-filtering-out-nan-from-a-data-selection-of-a-column-of-strings)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of worrying about the nan, you can use this to make sure it doesnt impact your operations atall.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x' : [1,2, np.nan ,3,5]})
df = df.convert_dtypes()
```

This let you work with Nans without pandas changing dtypes automatically and it will keep the items in the list as ints.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
​
df = pd.DataFrame({'x' : [1,2, np.nan ,3,5]})
df.replace(np.nan,"nan",inplace=True)
df = pd.DataFrame(map(str,df['x'])
```

Might not be the most elegant solution but gets  the job done. You might need to use a for loop if you have multiple columns.